# Dynamic row to column conversion in unix

Tags: awk, file-handling, normalize

My file looks like:

```
TABLE|COLUMN|VALUE  
vehicle|vehicle|vehicle
vehicle|make|toyota
vehicle|model|corolla 
vehicle|year|1986  
vehicle|color|black
vehicle|vehicle|vehicle
vehicle|make|honda
vehicle|model|odyssey
vehicle|year|2016
vehicle|color|black
vehicle|Number|123
```

Expected  output:-

```
Vehicle|make|model|year|color|number
vehicle|toyota|corolla|1986|black|
vehicle|honda|odyssey|2016|black|123
```

Is it possible using awk. as list of column is going to be dynamic.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** approach(but the order of columns is not strict):

The input file `inputfile` contains:

```
vehicle|vehicle|vehicle
vehicle|make|toyota
vehicle|model|corolla 
vehicle|year|1986  
vehicle|color|black
vehicle|vehicle|vehicle
vehicle|make|honda
vehicle|model|odyssey
vehicle|year|2016
vehicle|color|black
vehicle|Number|123
```

---

***awk*** script `transform.awk`:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { FS="|"; h= ""; maxRows=1; }
{ 
    tmp[$2]++; 
    if (maxRows < tmp[$2]) {
        maxRows=tmp[$2]
    }
    a[$2][tmp[$2]]=$3;
}
END{
    for (i in tmp) { h = sprintf("%s%10s %s", h, i, FS)}
    gsub(/\|$/, "", h); 
    print h "";
    for (j=1;j<=maxRows;j++){
        row=""
        for (i in a) {
            row = sprintf("%s%10s %s", row, a[i][j], FS);
        }
        gsub(/\|$/, "", row);
        print row;
    }    
}
```

---

***Usage***:

```
awk -f transform.awk inputfile
```

The output:

```
    model  |   vehicle |      year |    Number |     color |      make 
  corolla  |   vehicle |    1986   |       123 |     black |    toyota 
   odyssey |   vehicle |      2016 |           |     black |     honda
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply 

Expectation is :-


Vehicle|make|model|year|color|number

vehicle|toyota|corolla|1986|black|

vehicle|honda|odyssey|2016|black|123

Number 123 should fall in honda row.That would help.